# How are registers assigned in CUDA compilation

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvcc

It is said that the number of registers per kernel is important for CUDA optimization, and the upper boundary of this number can be set by "-maxrregcount=N" in nvcc. I could not understand this, because I thought that the number of registers can simply be determined by counting the local variables (and possibly the passed parameters) in the kernel. I know I am wrong, because the report from "nvcc --ptxas-options=-v" far exceed what I have counted in the way I thought. Could somebody deliberate a little bit on it?

Answer (score 2):

There is maximum number of registers per thread, in contemporaty GPUs in devices with Compute Capability 2.1 is 63 registers. Each Streaming Multiprocessor contain limited number of registers that are distributed among threads executed in threadblock. If You have small number  of threads per block You can be almost sure that the threads will get the maximal number of registers, but if there are a lot threads they will get smaller number of registers (it all depends on the total amount of memory used by threads and needs tayloring for each application).

Now all the variables that can't be stored in registers because there is lack of them goes to the local memory which is a part of global device memory and provides high memory latency in contrast to registers. This is called register spilling, you can read more about it here http://www.ece.umn.edu/~wxiao/ee5940/lecture8-2.pdf

It's very important to try to keep all the variables in registers. The impact of register spilling is often underestimated by new Cuda developers. I made some tests in which I artificially doubled the amount of memory used by threads and caused register spilling without any other computation costs and it increased the time of computations 5 times!
In small CUDA applications the number of registers is enough. You can find out how many variables goes to local memory by following the instruction in the pdf above.